# peano arithmetic - PA sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, formal-proofs

In using the non-logical axiom sentences of PA, I was trying a practice problem to get the hang of using the PA sentences:

$((S0 * S0) = S0)$

And so my approach was the following:

1. $\forall x_1((x_1 * 0) = 0)$ - Axiom(v)
2. $((S0 * 0) = 0)$ - 1, Universal elimination
3. $\forall x_1 \forall x_2((x_1 * Sx_2) = ((x_1 * x_2) + x_1))$ - Axiom(vi)
4. $\forall x_2((S0 * Sx_2) = ((S0 * x_2) + S0))$ - 3, universal elimination
5. $((S0 * S0) = ((S0 * 0) + S0))$ - 4, universal elimination
6. $((S0 * S0) = (S0))$ - 2, 5, substitution

When I got to #6, I thought that it looked good, but I can see that I have extra brackets at the end (perhaps I screwed up in my bracket management)

Any clue to what I may have missed, forgot during the proof process?

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: You forgot to mention that $0 + S0 = S0$ (from 2, 5 you only get $S0*S0 = 0 + S0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute 2 in 5 to get:

6. $S0*S0 = 0+S0$

Then you will need to use Axiom iv to get:

7. $0 + S0 = S(0+0)$

Use Axiom iii to get:

8. $0+0=0$

Substitute 8 in 7:

9. $0+S0=S0$

And finally substitute 9 in 6:

10. $S0*S0=S0$

Comment: Nice one! you have just proved $1 + 1 = 1$ and got a green tick for it! You and the OP need to agree between you what symbols to use for multiplication and addition and then be consistent about this.

Comment: @RobArthan Ha ha, that's great!  :). Guess the OP and I both missed it ... i'll edit.